# Passing API request parameter via props from child to parent

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 Api requests, one of them hangs on the child - from it, when I click on the picture, I get the track key and give it to the parent in the second Api request as a parameter so that it displays the information I need. But when I output this to the console, I get an empty message =(

**result** **[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1a2p.png)**

**CHILD**

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppContext } from '../MainContent'
import TrackTranding from './TrackTranding'
const ContentTrending = ({ onClick }) => {
  const { articles, setArticles } = React.useContext(AppContext)
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onClick(articles[e.target.dataset.attr].key) // get key from first api
  }
  return (
    <div className="main__content-trending">
      <p>Tranding right now</p>
      <div className="noflex-oneblock">
        <div className="main__content-trending-artist-title ">
          {
            articles.map((tracks, index) => {
              return (
                <div className='one' key={tracks.key}
                  onClick={handleClick}
                >
                  <TrackTranding
                    tracks={tracks}
                    index={index}
                  />
                  <audio src="#" id="audioTrack"></audio>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default ContentTrending
```

**PARENT**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react'
import MainContentBg from './MainBcg/ContentBg'
import MainContentTitle from './MainTitle/ContentTitle'
import ContentTrending from './MainTrending/ContentTrending'
export const AppContext = React.createContext()
const MainContent = () => {
    const [articles, setArticles] = React.useState([])
    const [detailse, setDetailse] = React.useState([])
    const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
    const handleClick = (name) => {
        setName(name)
        console.log(detailse) // --------------------------- error =()
    }
    const fetchData = () => {
        const chart = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://shazam.p.rapidapi.com/charts/track',
            params: { locale: 'en-US', pageSize: '20', startFrom: '0' },
            headers: {
                'X-RapidAPI-Key': '10eb9d1c65msh1029069c658be40p1197a5jsne7f1ee8c9f88',
                'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'shazam.p.rapidapi.com'
            }
        };
        axios.request(chart).then(data => {
            const tracksApi = data.data.tracks
            setArticles(tracksApi)
        })
        const details = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://shazam.p.rapidapi.com/songs/get-details',
            params: { key: { name }, locale: 'en-US' }, // ---------------------------------- param
            headers: {
                'X-RapidAPI-Key': '10eb9d1c65msh1029069c658be40p1197a5jsne7f1ee8c9f88',
                'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'shazam.p.rapidapi.com'
            }
        };
        axios.request(details).then(data => {
            const tracksDetails = data.data
            setDetailse(tracksDetails)
        })
    }
    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, []);
    return (
        <main className="main">
            <div className="main__content">
                <AppContext.Provider value={{ articles, setArticles }}>
                    <MainContentTitle />
                    <MainContentBg />
                    <ContentTrending onClick={handleClick} />
                </AppContext.Provider>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}
export default MainContent
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you call `fetchData` when the component first mounts the `name` state is set to an empty string `""`.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

Which you're passing in the `details` so essentially the object looks like this:

```js
const details = {
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://shazam.p.rapidapi.com/songs/get-details",
  params: { key: { name: "" }, locale: "en-US" }, // notice the empty string
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "10eb9d1c65msh1029069c658be40p1197a5jsne7f1ee8c9f88",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "shazam.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};
```

Instead what you can do is trigger the `useEffect` when the `name` changes. Which will now have the updated `name` from the `handleClick` from the `Child`.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [name]);
```

You probably want to change, currently you're setting the `key` to a object with another prop called `name`.

```js
params: { key: { name }, locale: 'en-US' }
```

to, this will make sure the `key` prop has the value from `name`

```js
params: { key: name, locale: 'en-US' }
```